# aws ec2 instance with two apps each having different access permissions to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am having an ec2 instance with 2 web apps named A and B.

How do I set different access permissions to S3 for each of these web-apps deployed in shared ec2 instance? In our case, I web app A to access s3 buckets related to its app only and not be able to access s3 buckets related to web-app B. Do the same for web-app B when it comes to access permissions of s3 buckets.

Please mark your solution as hack, if it is not the clean way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 2 separate IAM user for your application A and B, and In IAM user you must create roles for each IAM user where in IAM-roles you need to specify the s3 bucket policy and all details of specific bucket that you want to access through your application A or B. After creating IAM roles assign respective policies to each IAM user.

Now use these IAM user credentials in your respective applications for accessing specific bucket. If your'e accessing bucket via code nor a console then you should provide programmatic bucket access to that user. Please check on below link for more info.

[AWS - Writing IAM Policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)